# What is the meaning of the term "dependency" with regard to computer technology?

Tags: dependencies

I have researched this question, but can't find a consensus.  If "A depends on B", does the term "dependency" refer to:

1. A
2. B
3. The relationship between A and B

Does this term have different meanings in different subdomains of computer technology?

Comment: It has different meanings. It can be a dependency on a table in DBMS in this case please add more details and the context where you read it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't have a specific context in mind.  Because this term is so commonly used, I hoped for a common definition.  It seems B is more often called the dependency, though this runs against my intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B would be the dependency. You'd probably use "dependency" in the form "B is a dependency of "A". (I suppose Option #3 is also partly true, in that "dependency" describes the relationship.)

Answer (score 0):

In UML, it means that the method is capable of instantiating the object for a method call like

```
public class Main {
   Public void method() {
       Random random = new Random();
       random.nextInt();
   }
}
```

Or if you get it as a function parameter

```
Public class main {
   Public void method(Random random) { 
       random.nextInt();
   }
}
```

But if you actually store the object as a field variable, then it becomes an association. Here, `Main - - - > Random` is true.